# Irregular String Parsing on Python

Tags: python, django, string, parsing, web

I'm new to python/django and I am trying to suss out more effective information from my scraper. Currently, the scraper takes a list of comic book titles and correctly divides them into a CSV list in three parts (Published Date, Original Date, and Title). I then pass the current date and title through to different parts of my databse, which I do in my Loader script (convert mm/dd/yy into yyyy-mm-dd, save to "pub_date" column, title goes to "title" column).

A common string can look like this:

```
10/12/11|10/12/11|Stan Lee's Traveler #12 (10 Copy Incentive Cover)
```

I am successfully grabbing the date, but the title is trickier. In this instance, I'd ideally like to fill three different columns with the information after the second "|". The Title should go to "title", a charfield. the number 12 (after the '#') should go into the DecimalField "issue_num", and everything between the '()' 's should go into the "Special" charfield. I am not sure how to do this kind of rigorous parsing.

Sometimes, there are multiple #'s (one comic in particular is described as a bundle, "Containing issues #90-#95") and several have multiple '()' groups (such as, "Betrayal Of The Planet Of The Apes #1 (Of 4)(25 Copy Incentive Cover)
)

What would be a good road to start onto crack this problem? My knowledge of If/else statements quickly fell apart for the more complicated lines. How can I efficiently and (if possible) pythonic-ly parse through these lines and subdivide them so I can later slot them into the correct place in my database?

Comment: What you described is *not* rigorous parsing. You need to define what your output will be. For example, given "Containing issues #90-#95", what should go in the `issue_num`? Should the string "Containing issues" show up in the `title`? What about the multiple '()' groups? … Anyway, this kind of ad-hoc „smart parsing“ tends to descend into madness. Look for other ways to get the information, or prepare for a frustrating experience.

Comment: For the one instance of "#90-#95", I was going to give it a null value for the issue number and instead give it a volume number. For the multiple groups, the second set of ()'s always contains the part I want, so (theorhetically) I'd account for any that have two sets of parenthesies and ask it to only look at the second one, deleting (or at the very least not referencing) the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module `re`. For example, if you have the third `|`-delimited field of your sample record in a variable `s`, then you can do

```
match = re.match(r"^(?P<title>[^#]*) #(?P<num>[0-9]+) \((?P<special>.*)\)$", s)
title = match.groups('title')
issue = match.groups('num')
special = match.groups('special')
```

You'll get an `IndexError` in the last three lines for a missing field. Adapt the RE until it parses everything your want.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the title is the hard part, it sounds like you can handle the dates etc yourself. The problem is that there is not *one* rule that can parse every title but there are *many* rules and you can only guess which one works on a particular title.

I usually handle this by creating a list of rules, from most specific to general and try them out one by one until one matches.

To write such rules you can use the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module or even [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

The general idea goes like this:

```
class CantParse(Exception): 
    pass

# one rule to parse one kind of title
import re
def title_with_special( title ):
    """ accepts only a title of the form
     <text> #<issue> (<special>) """
    m = re.match(r"[^#]*#(\d+) \(([^)]+)\)", title)
    if m:
        return m.group(1), m.group(2)
    else:
        raise CantParse(title)


def parse_extra(title, rules):
    """ tries to parse extra information from a title using the rules """
    for rule in rules:
        try:
            return rule(title)
        except CantParse:
            pass

    # nothing matched
    raise CantParse(title)


# lets try this out
rules = [title_with_special] # list of rules to apply, add more functions here
titles = ["Stan Lee's Traveler #12 (10 Copy Incentive Cover)",
          "Betrayal Of The Planet Of The Apes #1 (Of 4)(25 Copy Incentive Cover) )"]

for title in titles:
    try:
        issue, special = parse_extra(title, rules)
        print "Parsed", title, "to issue=%s special='%s'" % (issue, special)
    except CantParse:
        print "No matching rule for", title
```

As you can see the first title is parsed correctly, but not the 2nd. You'll have to write a bunch of rules that account for every possible title format in your data.

Comment: Thanks! This gets me to identify the issue numbers/special, but how do I then go on to record them in the loop? book.issue_num = ??

Comment: @Alxjrvs: there is still much to do to parse all your title formats. The rule function simply returns `(issue_num, special)` pairs so you use that.

Comment: Thanks. I am a little lost  - how would I go about calling that in the script? I am not sure what is holding the values of the issue number and the special.

Comment: Nevermind my last comment - a transcription error on my part made me go briefly stupid. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression is the way to go. But if you fill uncomfortably writing them, you can try a small parser that I wrote (https://github.com/hgrecco/stringparser). It translates a string format (PEP 3101) to a regular expression. In your case, you will do the following:

```
>>> from stringparser import Parser
>>> p = Parser(r"{date:s}\|{date2:s}\|{title:s}#{issue:d} \({special:s}\)")
>>> x = p("10/12/11|10/12/11|Stan Lee's Traveler #12 (10 Copy Incentive Cover)")
OrderedDict([('date', '10/12/11'), ('date2', '10/12/11'), ('title', "Stan Lee's Traveler "), ('issue', 12), ('special', '10 Copy Incentive Cover')])
>>> x.issue
12
```

The output in this case is an (ordered) dictionary. This will work for any simple cases and you might tweak it to catch multiple issues or multiple ()

One more thing: notice that in the current version you need to manually escape regex characters (i.e. if you want to find |, you need to type \|). I am planning to change this soon.